# Is it possible to get the current PID in a seccomp filter?

Tags: c, bpf, ebpf, seccomp

When working with seccomp userspace notifications (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/userspace-api/seccomp_filter.html) via SECCOMP_RET_USER_NOTIF I found the PID as part of the seccomp_notif struct extremely useful for some filtering decisions.
In ebpf filters helper functions, like bpf_get_current_pid_tgid(), can be used to obtain such information. But since seccomp only seems to support the classic BPF I was wondering if there is another way.
Inside a seccomp filter as far as I know it is only possible to access the seccomp_data structure.
Is there a way to get specific information like the PID inside a seccomp filter directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot get that information from the seccomp filter itself unless it is part of the syscall arguments. To retrieve the PID, you would have to e.g. give control to a userspace ptracer process or rely on `SECCOMP_RET_USER_NOTIF` as you mentioned.